# Why can I write to sessionStorage from an iframe on the first try, but not any consecutive tries? (Chrome Version 74)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, same-origin-policy

This issue has shown up in the latest version of Chrome (74.0.3729.108). This is unique to the local filesystem, as I have other ways of loading up neighboring documents in iframes when the app is on a server.

In my app, we have been able to load up documents from the filesystem with JavaScript by writing iframes to the DOM, and then having the document in the iframe write it's `innerHTML` to `sessionStorage`. Once the iframe is done loading, we catch that with the `onload` attribute on the iframe and handle getting the item written to `sessionStorage`.

I have narrowed this down to some bare-bones code and found that this works only on the first try, and then any tries after the first fail.

#### Here is a minimal HTML document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chrome iFrame Tester</title>
  <script src="iframe-load.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="OnLoad()">
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Here is the JavaScript:

```js
var urls = ['file://C:/Users/afrench/Documents/Other/Misc%20Code/Chrome%20iFrame/Doc1.html', 
            'file://C:/Users/afrench/Documents/Other/Misc%20Code/Chrome%20iFrame/Doc2.html'];

HandleLoad = function () {
  'use strict';

  var data;

  try {
    data = window.sessionStorage['data'];
    delete window.sessionStorage['data'];
  } catch (ignore) {
    // something went wrong
  }

  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  window.document.body.removeChild(container);

  if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
    var resultContainer = document.getElementById('result');
    resultContainer.innerHTML += data;
  }

  if (urls.length > 0) {
    OnLoad();
  }
}

function OnLoad() {
  var url = urls[0];

  if (url) {
    urls.splice(0, 1);

    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.id = 'container';
    container.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    window.document.body.appendChild(container);
    container.innerHTML = '<iframe src="' + url + '" onload="HandleLoad();"></iframe>';
  }
}
```

In the filesystem, we have the HTML written into `index.html`, and right next to it are two minimal HTML files, `Doc1.html` and `Doc2.html`. Their contents are both identical except the identifying sentence in the body's div:

#### Neighbor document HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chrome iFrame Tester</title>
  <script>
    function OnLoad() {
      try {
        window.sessionStorage['data'] = window.document.body.innerHTML;
      } catch {
        // no luck
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="OnLoad()">
  <div>This is Doc 1's content!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When this is run, we should see the content HTML of the two neighbor documents written to the `result` div in `index.html`.

When I run this minimal example, I can see that the content is successfully written to `sessionStorage` and then to the DOM for the first document, but the next try fails. What can I do to get it to work consistently, and what is happening here that it fails?

Comment: What should the final result be?

Comment: @Herohtar you should see the body content from the two neighbor html documents written in `index.html`. I just updated the post to say that.

Comment: If you don't destroy the iframes after you're done, you can hop inside each iframe after load-time in the console. There's a drop-down in the top-left (by default is says `top`) of the Devtools console that lets you jump into a particular iframe and, e.g., run more `sessionStorage.foo = ...` statements. I played around with this but couldn't make any sense of Chrome's behavior. Try setting properties and seeing if those properties are reflected in the top and sibling frame. (Might be worth making a simple no-scripts parent-and-children iframe page for this test.)

Comment: Testing it out in the console, I can see `sessionStorage` is separated between the parent window and the iframes, as if this shouldn't even work on the first try, but it does.

Comment: There is definitely something strange going on. By inserting some `debugger` statements and switching between the "Sources" and "Application" tabs in Chrome I was actually able to get it to display the Doc2 content, but it was *instead* of the Doc1 content rather than in addition to it.

Comment: Is this question about getting this specific method to work and/or about learning *why* it doesn't work? Because I have no clue what is causing the behavior here, but if those aren't important I can give you an alternate solution that should work.

Comment: @Herohtar I don't necessarily need this method to work. I was hoping someone could illuminate why it isn't working, but the end goal is to get the body content from the child iframes when they load to the parent in a synchronous manner.This issue seems to be part of Chrome's security update that happened this last week, and I put in an issue for it to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is causing the weird behavior, so hopefully someone else can provide some insight on what exactly is going on here.

In the meantime, here is an alternative solution using [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage):

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chrome iFrame Tester</title>
  <script src="iframe-load.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="OnLoad()">
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

## iframe-load.js

```
var urls = ['file://C:/Users/afrench/Documents/Other/Misc%20Code/Chrome%20iFrame/Doc1.html', 
            'file://C:/Users/afrench/Documents/Other/Misc%20Code/Chrome%20iFrame/Doc2.html'];

window.addEventListener('message', event => {
  'use strict';

  var data = event.data;

  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  window.document.body.removeChild(container);

  if (data) {
    var resultContainer = document.getElementById('result');
    resultContainer.innerHTML += data;
  }

  if (urls.length > 0) {
    OnLoad();
  }
})

function OnLoad() {
  var url = urls.shift();

  if (url) {
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.id = 'container';
    container.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    window.document.body.appendChild(container);
    container.innerHTML = '<iframe src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
  }
}
```

## Doc1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chrome iFrame Tester</title>
  <script>
    function OnLoad() {
      window.parent.postMessage(window.document.body.innerHTML, '*');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="OnLoad()">
  <div>This is Doc 1's content!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works! I actually have a whole framework set up for the `postMessage` method, the way to do it from the iframe was alluding me. Thanks.